# Removing Duplicate Values within a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an output that has duplicate values within a single row, my goal is to remove any duplicates that exist in a single row.

I've written many lines of case statements to try to correct this issue, but am hoping there is an easier way

Here is an example output:

```
BRAND_SEG S_GROUP_1  CS_GROUP_2 CS_GROUP_3 CS_GROUP_4 CS_GROUP_5

       3D      G11C        G11C        G3C       G11C        G1C
```

My goal would be to have it look like this:

```
BRAND_SEG  S_GROUP_1  CS_GROUP_2 CS_GROUP_3

       3D       G11C         G3C        G1C
```

Comment: Why `CS_GROUP_2` becomes `G3C` instead of `G11C` in the second dataset? Same with `CS_GROUP_3`. Also, you should provide the sample data you're querying from.

Comment: Please present a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: Pavel, it changes because I am hoping to eliminate duplicate values within the row. I'm not sure how the code should be written

Comment: There are ways to do this using dynamic SQL, but they're extremely complicated and messy.  Are you sure you really need a solution like this?  When dealing with relational data the columns should be static.  A better way to represent the results would be a table with three columns: BRAND_SEG, S_GROUP_NUMBER, and S_GROUP_VALUE.  99% of the time when someone asks for dynamic columns they don't really want dynamic columns.  If you think you have an exceptional case you should explain why.  (That's probably why you got down votes, people assuming you're asking an XY question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot and reaggregate.  In Oracle 12C, you can do:

```
select brand_seg
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then s_group end) as s_group_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then s_group end) as s_group_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then s_group end) as s_group_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then s_group end) as s_group_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then s_group end) as s_group_5
from (select t.brand_seg, s_group,
             dense_rank() over (order by s_group) as seqnum
      from t cross join lateral
           (select S_GROUP_1 as s_group from dual union  -- to remove duplicates
            select S_GROUP_2 as s_group from dual union
            select S_GROUP_3 as s_group from dual union
            select S_GROUP_4 as s_group from dual union
            select S_GROUP_5 as s_group from dual 
           ) s
      ) s
group by brand_seg;
```

In earlier versions of Oracle, you can use `union` instead of a lateral join.